# RavenDB database restore: Operation failed: Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use

Tags: ravendb

A year ago, when we started using RavenDB, we quickly hit this error in production:

> Operation failed: Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use

We found out through some forums, that we could get rid of this by not running RavenDB as an IIS website, but as a service. We did, and never saw the error again.

Until now: I'm setting up a new environment and thought, I'd give it a whirl with running RavenDB off IIS, but the error quickly reappeared.

Facts and what I've tried:

- running off v.30155 on a commercial license
- using a custom AppPool (called *RavenApplicationPool*)
- have data-folder separate from IIS dir (through `Raven/WorkingDir` AppSetting)
- *RavenApplicationPool* user has "Full control" permissions on both IIS folder and data-folder
- Windows Authentication installed and enabled for website
- [overlapped recycle disabled](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/installation/IIS) for app-pool
- webdav-publishing not installed (as requested in [setup docs](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/installation/IIS))
- hitting my keyboard (no luck)

The error occurs at random when site has been running for a few minutes. It also occurs when trying to restore a backup using the following command:

> C:\RavenDBExecutables\Server\raven.Server.exe --restore-source=c:\SOME_PATH\my-db-backup.raven --restore-database-name=my-db --restore-database=http://localhost:8080

(the RavenDBExecutables folder is merely the zip of binaries/executables et.c. - it does not overlap with the IIS website folder)

When running the restore, these folders are created:

- IndexDefinitions (contains a lot of files ending in .index)
- Indexes (lot of folders with integer names)
- logs (empty)
- system (empty)
- temp (empty)
- root folder (*my-db*) is empty, i.e. no *Data* file, *.resource.database* or *raven-data.ico* as with working db's

After failed import, if I visit http://localhost:8080/docs/Raven/Restore/Status, I get

*a lot of lines like "Copying PATH_TO_INDEX_FILE", *

> "Esent Restore: Failure! Could not restore database!",
>       "Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileAccessDeniedException: Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetRestoreInstance(JET_INSTANCE
>   instance, String source, String destination, JET_PFNSTATUS
>   statusCallback)\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Storage.Esent.Backup.RestoreOperation.Execute()",
>       "Unable to restore database Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use"

What can it be then?

Comment: Check your system event logs, I actually had this error just last night and it turned out the app pool did not have permissions to the data directories.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that IIS by default does overlapped recycle. 
That means that both versions of the app are running (and both are trying to use the same resources).
With overlapped recycled set to false, that shouldn't happen.
We have seen similar errors when users have set two databases to the same path

Comment: Hi Ayende, as I wrote, I have already disabled overlapped recycle (actually, the installer had done it for me when creating the app-pool). So unfortunately that is not the solution for me in this case.